# "So verb-ed as (not) to"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a question regarding "*so v-ed as not to*". Here are some examples:

> Reading their litanies of untruth, **so concocted as to** spread the maximum terror and mistrust and discontent, is not an arduous undertaking.
> (The Islamic State, Ebola, and the Appeal of Conspiracy)

> The liberal epic is that of the individual threatened by concentrations of privilege, prejudice, and power, and liberated from these by the creation of a sacred sphere of noninterference as well as by that of a state **so conceived and constructed as not to** be capable of becoming an enemy again.
> (Jane and Minerva)

I guess I know what "so as to" means (like in order to), and maybe also what "so *adj* as to" means (e.g. "*I am not so foolish as to say that*" I guess means that someone is foolish to the extent that he can even say that, right?). But with the construction in the title I get a bit confused. I don't know how to analyze it. Can you help?

Comment: I cannot understand  your question as given in the post's title. And I think the author probably meant to say: is an arduous undertaking....in any case,

Comment: @Lambie Is it the v-ed part you don't understand? I have edited it

Comment: I finally got it,the issue is that both paragraphs are in pretty poor English and I just don't have the energy to write an entire answer. So conceived= conceived in a such a way that x.

Comment: @Lambie Is the "such" referring to the clause after "as not to" or something else? I can't think of other things it could possibly refer to in these two examples.

Comment: Yes, to the next clause.

Answer (score 1):

The supposition in the original question that “so as” means “in order to” is correct.

> So concocted as to spread terror

means

> Concocted in order to spread terror

Analytically, the question is not so straightforward.

In your first example, "concocted" is a type of adjective, called a "participle, derived from a verb. Alternatively, you can view it as a passive verb subject to ellipsis. For example, you can use a pure adjective in such a construction

> Reading their litanies of untruth, false even in easily verified details, ...

"False" is not a verb of any sort. The structure that you are seeing is an adjectival phrase modifying the preceding noun. It is quite common to use participles in that way.

You can interpret a perfect participle used in such a construction as an abbreviated relative clause in the passive voice:

> Reading their litanies of untruth, which were concocted so as to spread ...

Going on to your second sentence,

> ... a state so conceived and constructed as not to be capable of being an enemy again

means

> ... a state that has been conceived and contructed so as not to be capable of being an enemy again

As a matter of style, I would find both sentences clearer were "so" and "as" not separated.

> concocted so as to spread

> conceived and constructed so as to be incapable of

But style is a matter of opinion.

Comment: So you are saying that it indicates purpose? 

Comment: The "so ... as" indicates purpose.

Comment: I wonder what "so" means in the original sentence. Was "so" used to mean "in this way"?

Comment: @Sink It was used to denote purpose: "so as" = "in order to."

Comment: @RayButterworth I did not interpret the original question to be based on not grasping “so as” = “in order to.” See the first sentence of the second paragraph that explicitly makes that connection. I viewed the original question as being analytic in nature rather than lexical. But I shall edit my answer to confirm the original poster’s understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"so concocted as to spread the maximum terror": concocted in a way designed to spread the maximum terror.